# Can I use one location method at a time on Android and turn off other methods?Want to get the reading from the WiFi , then the cellular then from GNSS

Tags: geolocation, location

I need to write an app that allow me to select one method at a time to capture the location, Lat and Long, and then try another method then another one.

For example, I would like to use the WiFi with RTT, then the cellular network then the GNSS.

How can I do that? what service/API/Method/Instance enables me to do it?

Thanks,
Tareq

I was trying the fusion function to be stopped as well as the A-GPS. It didn't work, I am missing how to turn ON and OFF the perspective location method.